# Discretization with impulse invariance

Tags: control-theory, z-transform

I came to the note:
$$ X(z)= \sum_{}^{} \frac{N(s)} {D'(s)} * \frac {z} {z - e ^ {Ts}}.at.s=sp $$

But in the textbook it's written in the form
$$ X(z)= \sum_{}^{} {residue.of \frac {X(z) z} {z - e ^ {Ts}}.at.s=sp} $$

where N(s) and D(s) are the numerator and denominator of the X(s)

So which one is right?

Comment: Can you please specify what each symbol means and use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/76466).

Comment: N(s) and D(s) are the numerator and den of the X(s)